# inserting a node in sorted doubly linked list

Tags: data-structures, insert, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, sortedlist

Insert Node in a doubly sorted linked list After each insertion, the list should be sorted

Node is defined as

```
struct Node
   {
     int data;
     Node *next;
     Node *prev;
   }
```

And a logic of function is written below..

```
Node* SortedInsert(Node *head,int data)
{
    // Complete this function
   // Do not write the main method. 
    struct Node *newn= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
    newn->data= data;
    newn->next= newn->prev= NULL;

    struct Node *trav=head, *pre=NULL;

    if(head==NULL)
        head= newn;
    else if(newn->data <= trav->data)
    {
        newn->next= trav;
        trav->prev= newn;
        head= newn;
    }
    else
    {
        while(trav->data <= newn->data)
        {
            pre= trav;
            trav=trav->next; 
        }
        pre= trav;
        trav=trav->next;

        newn->next= trav;
        trav->prev= newn;
        pre->next= newn;
        newn->prev= pre;
    }
    return head;
}
```

please let me know what is problem with the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a small mistake,first of all the space is allocated this way:

```
struct Node *newn= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

and the right else condition is:

```
else
{           
 while(trav!=NULL&&trav->data <= newn->data)
 {
  pre= trav;
  trav=trav->next; 
 }
 newn->prev=pre;
 newn->next=trav;
 pre->next=newn;
 if(trav!=NULL)
  trav->prev=newn;
}
```